# Alsa capturing mono microphone as right channel of stereo

Tags: alsa, recording

The laptop microphone is mono but audio seems to get captured as stereo.
The resulting recording has the sounds captured by the mic in the right channel and for some reason whatever sound is currently playing (speaker or headphones) is recorded as the left channel.

Telling arecord to use one channel doesn't seem to have any effect

```
arecord -c 1 -d 3 -f dat foo.wav
```

And setting audacity to capture mono instead of stereo results in nothing getting recorded.

What could be causing this and how do I get capture to work properly?

amixer output: http://pastebin.com/0r09Ln1E

Answer (score -1):

No built-in audio device supports playback or recording with less than two channels.

How the single microphone channel is routed to the recording device depends on the hardware. This cannot be changed by software.

Just record two channels and then throw one away.

Comment: While this works for recording to a file, I can't really use it with applications like skype